# Poisson Conditional distribution

Tags: conditional-probability, poisson-distribution

Let $X \sim Poisson(\lambda)$ and $Y \sim Poisson(\lambda p)$, where $p\in(0,1)$. How to prove $Y|X=x$ will follow a binomial distribution with $x$ and $p$ as parameters for $x = 0,1,2,...$ i.e.

$$f_{Y|X}(y|x)= \binom{x}{y}p^y(1-p)^{x-y}$$

I know the answer will be $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$, but I am stuck at the steps of how to prove it.

Comment: I think you've left out some information. For instance this claim is not true if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Y is dependent on X. X is the amount of people who enter a restaurant and Y is the number of female among them with a probability p

Comment: Doesn't the conditional distribution $Y \mid X=x$ follow directly from the setup of the problem then? Each person has probability $p$ of being a child, so the number of children out of $x$ people is $y$ with probability $\binom{x}{y} p^y (1-p)^{x-y}$.

Comment: Thank you for the reasoning.